# How to display array elements in new line?

Tags: arrays

I am trying to display array elements in new lines, it all displays in same line. I have tried a few related answer but no luck. My code is below:

```
 //Line 
            $("#display_File_most").text(counter.join(" ", "<br/>"));
```

Thanks for your time:)

Comment: Change `.text` to `.html`.

Comment: Thanks, same thing still :S

Comment: you're doing `counter.join(" ")`, the second argument, `"<br/>"`, is not expected and therefore ignored. Why did you add that `" "` there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey change this line from `$("#display_File_most").text(counter.join(" ", "<br/>"));` to  `$("#display_File_most").html(counter.join("<br/>"));` and it will work.